# Merging two dataframes of different length (inner join)

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, etl

I am trying to merge two different dataframes of varying length into one single dataframe by using inner join.  Below are my dataset description.

```
threshold_shaped.shape[0] 
611
beer.shape[0]
1586614
```

Both the dataset has beer_name as a column in it. Beer_name is unique in threshold_shape whereas it is not unique in beer.
beer has two columns "brewery_name" and "beer_name" 
My objective is to merge these two dataframes together based on beer_name and to keep the values in threshold_shape. i.e., I wanted to have 611 rows with a new column "brewery_name" created in a new dataframe.

**What I tried?**

```
Main_dataframe=pd.merge(left=threshold_merged,right=beer,how="inner",on='beer_name')

Main_dataframe.shape[0]
592932
```

But I wanted to have 611 rows as the threshold dataframe has only 611 rows .

Could you please help in achieving the same.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Problem is with duplicates in one or both index values. First remove it and then get expected output.

Comment: if your beer dataset has duplicate on beer_name, you will get more than 611 rows even with inner join. The only way for that is to first dedupe beer dataset and then join.

Comment: Great it works good. Just removed the duplicates in beer name and merged as mentioned by you people